# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash how to read errors

Tags: ios, debugging

Testing my app which gets location data from an api and displays in a table view. Was testing something else today and app crashed - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0X0). What does this mean and how do I read the information provided by Xcode to figure out how to fix?

[image: crash]

[image: crash![][2]]

[image: crash]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXEC_BAD_ACCESS usually means that you are trying to access an object which is not in memory or probably not properly initialized.

Check in your code, 
if you are accessing your Dictionary variable after it is somehow removed? 
is your variable properly initialized? You might have declared the variable but did not initialize it and accessing it.

There could be a ton of reasons and cant say much without seeing any code.

Try to turn on NSZombieOjects - this might provide you more debug information.  Refer to here [How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

IF you would like to know where and when exactly is the error occurring, you could check for memory leaks using instruments. This might be helpful http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided. My guess is that the library is calling out to a block you provided. Inside that block is a Dictionary which has something wrong with it.

Good luck!